# SQL Where NOT Exists Insert

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am trying to run an query using php into a database, I need to check if the customers `address` is already exists then do not insert, but if not exists then insert into table, I have based it around the following:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO address(id,address_type)
   SELECT('1111','bill')FROM DUAL 
   WHERE NOT EXISTS 
      (SELECT * FROM address 
       WHERE id='1111' AND address_type='bill')";

$n = mysql_query($query, $connect ) or die(mysql_error());
```

This allows me to insert just the `id` but not the `address_type`. 
I will have the same `id` for both `bill` & `ship` addresses making a unique field not possible.

I have about 8 fields to insert, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the size of address_type field? I notice that you are trying to insert "billing" where as address_type is "bill" in the internal query.

Comment: Do you not have an autonumber field just so you can select a unique value?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense.  You are inserting into one table but checking for existence in another.

Comment: sorry edited to make more sense! 

address_type will only ever have either bill or ship in it. I have an Unique_id field that numbers each entry but unsure of how I could use that in this query

Comment: Error it gives is Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: [Please avoid using `mysql_query()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: I wouldn't expect the Operand should contian 1 column error with this SQL, since `SELECT * ` is permitted in an `EXISTS` subquery (as opposed to `SELECT 1` for example) but maybe some faulty parsing is happening because you are leaving out a lot of whitespace surrounding `()`.  Add space after `address, SELECT, FROM`

Comment: It does look like a better solution to what you're attempting would be to just use `INSERT IGNORE` and create a `UNIQUE` index across `(id, address_type)`. If the row already exists, a new one won't be inserted and MySQL won't report a duplicate key error.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately it still shows the same error.

Comment: I will look into INSERT IGNORE and see if that would be a more efficient way of doing this.

Comment: I have added an UNIQUE index across (id,address_type) and this seems to have created the desired affect using an normal INSERT INTO query. 
thank you for your help! :)

Comment: Please, [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and consider using PDO, [it's not as hard as you think](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "INSERT INTO address(id,address_type)
   SELECT('1111','bill')FROM DUAL 
   WHERE NOT EXISTS 
      (SELECT * FROM address 
       WHERE id='1111' )";
```

remove address_type='bill' and check